# Setting frame rate while saving video file using GstElement

Tags: ubuntu, gtk, gstreamer

I have a terminal command which can display video frames from web camera as source and save to a location. The terminal command:

```
gst-launch v4l2src ! 'video/x-raw-yuv,width=640,height=480,framerate=30/1' ! \
queue ! videorate ! 'video/x-raw-yuv,framerate=30/1' ! theoraenc ! \
queue ! oggmux ! filesink location=me_funny_dancing.ogg
```

I can create the video-rate element:

```
GstElement *video_save_rate = gst_element_factory_make("videorate","video_save_rate");
```

but how can I set the frame rate `video/x-raw-yuv,framerate=30/1` so that I can link with the video-rate object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might it have to do with [set-video-resolution-fps](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-bad-plugins/html/gst-plugins-bad-plugins-camerabin.html)?

Comment: I know this is an old Q&A but do you mind making an [edit] to go into detail so this isn't a link only answer?